# Writing a file to an Ubuntu 18.04 directory using postgres query tool

Tags: linux, postgresql

I have a Python program calling postgres queries then showing the results on the screen. So far Python and postgres both run on Windows. Now I want to move the database to Ubuntu.

I therefore want to write a file from postgres query tool to an Ubuntu 18.04 directory. Under Windows (old setting), writing the file from postgres query tool works without complications. Using the new postgres database on Ubuntu, I have added postgres to my personal (=mm) user group and changed the permissions of the corresponding folder (755). Even added a file temp.csv and changed the permissions of that file as well (755). Still, when trying...

```
create table temp (test text);
insert into temp(test) VALUES ('Sample text');
copy (select * from temp) to '/home/mm/temp.csv';
```

... I get ...

> ERROR: could not open file "/home/mm/temp.csv" for writing: Keine Berechtigung [=No permission]
>   
>   SQL Status:42501
>   Hinweis:COPY TO instructs the PostgreSQL server process to write a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.

I could write to a samba directory with "free for all" permissions, but I don't want to do that for data security reasons.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: `Hinweis:COPY TO instructs the PostgreSQL server process to write a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.`

Comment: Thanks, but...: Do I really need to change the database interface setup to do this? I would have many more questions if that was necessary.

Comment: The `COPY` command is executed by the server, as user `postgres` (typically). It can only read/write where user postgres can read/write. The  `\copy` command is run *in the frontend* (could be `psql`, but most middleware implements it in some way)

Comment: Thanks. I get it - It's permission 775 not 755. Stupid me. Still a lot to learn.